# how to Implement the add and member methods of the SetImpl.java?

Tags: java

Everyone. Anyone can help me how to start this question. I am not very clear about it. Very appreciate.

**The question is:**
Implement the *add* and *member* methods of the **SetImpl.java**. Note that it is strongly recommended that you do not allow duplicates during add - that would make other methods more challenging to implement.

The following is the java coding about **SetImpl.java**:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SetImpl<T> implements Set<T>{


    // container class for linked list nodes
    private class Node<T>{
        public T val;
        public Node<T> next;
    }

    private Node<T> root; // empty set to begin with

    // no need for constructor


    // add new element to the set by checking for membership.. if not
    // then add to the front of the list
    public void add(T val){
    }

    // delete element from the list - may be multiple copies.
    public void delete(T val){

    }


    // membership test of list
    public boolean member(T val){

        return false;
    }

    // converts to a list
    public List<T> toList(){
        ArrayList<T> res;
        return res;
    }

    // does simple set union   
    public void union(Set<T> s){

    }

}
```

Anyone can give me some tips about this question?
Thanks very much!

**First try**

```
private Node < T > root = null;
private Node < T > head = null;
private Node < T > tail = null;
public void add(T val) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = tail = new Node < T > ();
        head.val = val;
        root.next = tail;
        tail = head;
    } else {
        tail.next = new Node < T > ();
        tail = tail.next;
        tail.val = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a pretty good tip: Start implementing it and once you hit a wall of bricks we will help you.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework/uni course exercise question. You should be aware that many institutions these days have software to help them detect when people have made excessive use of the internet for assistance.

Comment: don't be to harsh on him either, he asks help to start not solution. Show us first what you tried. spoiler hint : `// empty set to begin with` and `// add new element to the set...`

Comment: This is my homework. Why i post the question for some assistance because i really don't know where i can start about this question. I am new in java. I just need some tips about this.

Comment: @hjxlpp like Peter said, try first and show us what you tried. then we can help.

Comment: Hi,TecHunter,thanks for your understanding. This is my coding what i have tried followed by your suggestion. Could you help me check is it correct thinking about this question until now? Thanks very much!

    private Node<T> root=null;
    private Node<T> head=null;
    private Node<T> tail=null;

    public void add(T val){
     if(head==null){
      head=tail=new Node<T>();
      head.val=val;
      root.next=tail;
      tail=head;
     }
     else{
      tail.next=new Node<T>();
      tail=tail.next;
      tail.val=val;
     }
    }

Comment: @hjxlpp my eyes are burning right now.... editing your post just this once to show you the way it's done around here...

Comment: @hjxlpp - Please edit your question with the code in your comment in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is just hints on how you should go in your logic :

```
public class SetImpl<T> implements Set<T>{


    // container class for linked list nodes
    ///// It is said "Linked list" --> first hint google that
    private class Node<T>{
        public T val;
        public Node<T> next;
    }

    private Node<T> root; // empty set to begin with
    ///// So that's my "root" which means I will have descendants

    // no need for constructor


    // add new element to the set by checking for membership.. if not
    // then add to the front of the list
    // Basically here everything is said. 
    // 1- check membership
    // 2- if true do nothing (as it has been said, it's a Set, if you don't know why I say that google Set Collections
    //if false (which means the val I want to add is not in my set) then I can add it to the Set
    public void add(T val){
    }

    // delete element from the list - may be multiple copies.
    public void delete(T val){

    }


    // membership test of list
    // that's recursive calls. How do you check that? where do you store your values?
    // It's true if your current Node.val attribute == the value OR if the rest of the Nodes has the value as member. Here you really need to know about Linked List
    public boolean member(T val){

        return false;
    }

    // converts to a list
    public List<T> toList(){
        ArrayList<T> res;
        return res;
    }

    // does simple set union   
    public void union(Set<T> s){

    }

}
```

**Your implementation**

```
private Node < T > root = null;
private Node < T > head = null;
private Node < T > tail = null;
public void add(T val) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = tail = new Node < T > ();
        head.val = val;
        root.next = tail;
        tail = head;
    } else {
        tail.next = new Node < T > ();
        tail = tail.next;
        tail.val = val;
    }
}
```

My guess is you don't need to add fields in such exercises. It's already half baked for you. Check out [how linked list works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). I'm lazy so I provide first "linked list" result from google. :)
Have fun